# USB Storage / Stick no longer recognized after unsafe removal

Tags: usb-storage

Actually I did not even remove the USB-Stick, just the laptop went into power save (sleep) mode. After that the USB Stick is no longer recognized - not by any USB port on this or a different laptop. It is not even shown in computermanagement or file explorer.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? I would like to keep the data, and would like to recover the stick.

Comment: It's probably dead.

Comment: you killed it, time for a new one.

Comment: If you have a Linux handy, you could see if you get some Kernel output (```sudo dmesg -w```) when you connect it. If there is output, append it to your question. However, probably @GabrielaGarcia is right: It's dead.